# How to handle a "Wait" or "loading for a web application

Tags: selenium, sleep

I am learning selenium by writing automation code for one web application.
When a page get loaded , I am calling Thread.sleep() method and then setting an element ID.

In below code , first clicking submit button and then waiting for "Success"  div loader.

```
    isElementPresent("btn_settingsSubmit_id").click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    
            
    WebDriverWait waitSet = new WebDriverWait(driver,40);
    waitSet.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='jq-toast-loader jq-toast-loaded']"))));
    
    //*********************************Add Priority***************************************
    Thread.sleep(6000);
    WebElement PT=isElementPresent("lnk_priorityTab_id");
    PT.click();
    WebDriverWait wait02 = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
    wait02.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("preloader")));
```

Here issue is if internet is slow or server takes time to send response  then sleep is not helpful and getting an error like element id not found.

which is the way to handle this page/ element loading?

Comment: Use the same `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf()` for Id. What `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf()` does. This will wait until element is visible. Once element is visible this will move to next statement and no longer wait for specified time.

Comment: Can we use this for all elements or at some place only ?

Comment: You can use wherever you needed to identify element. This is best practice to avoid synchronization error.

Comment: Where is it failing? on the invisibility of "preloader"? Is 30 seconds not long enough? Or is this failing on "isElementPresent("lnk_priorityTab_id");" which you have not added a wait for yet.

Comment: @DMart I applied a web driver wait for  "isElementPresent("lnk_priorityTab_id") " until this element's visible. It runs fine sometimes and sometimes it gives stale element reference exception. It becomes uncertain when the code will run and when it will break.How to handle this?

Comment: staleelement refers to the element you saved no longer being in the DOM, perhaps a page refresh?